# How to Detect or prevent proxy browsing

Tags: php, html, apache, proxy, server

I am built a web site and i want to restrict proxy browsing in my website.I have search and google this problem but i do not get appropriate way to do it so,
Is there any way to detect/prevent proxy browsing?

Comment: Some things you should google up: HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR, Public Proxy Lists, https://check.torproject.org/cgi-bin/TorBulkExitList.py and much more...

Comment: There are several ways to improve proxy detection. However, a 100% fool prove detection doesn't exist.

Answer (score 4):

**Why would you try to block proxies?**
Usually server / website owners try to block proxies to prevent their members from bypassing IP bans or hiding their identities while doing malicious stuff on the server / website. Although I can understand the reasoning behind it, detecting proxy servers causes more trouble than it solves.
**Downsides of detecting proxies**

1. The better your detection methods, the slower your server will become.
2. It's never 100% fool proof! No matter what you try, you can never detect and block all of them.
3. There are a few select people who have legitimite reasons to use a proxy. People from China for example where their covernment blocks a lot of websites from them.

**So what should I do instead?**
There are better and more secure ways of protecting your server / website. There's way to many to name them all, but a couple of them are:

- *Regular Expressions - To control user input.*
- *Secure File Upload / Download - For more info, see [this](https://www.exploit-db.com/docs/164.pdf) PDF file.*
- *Account activation through something like SMS - Instead of IP banning, block the Phone Number.*

**Some ways to improve proxy detection**

*Header detection (Doesn't work vs Anonymous proxies):*

```
$proxy_headers = array(
    'HTTP_VIA',
    'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR',
    'HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR',
    'HTTP_X_FORWARDED',
    'HTTP_FORWARDED',
    'HTTP_CLIENT_IP',
    'HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR_IP',
    'VIA',
    'X_FORWARDED_FOR',
    'FORWARDED_FOR',
    'X_FORWARDED',
    'FORWARDED',
    'CLIENT_IP',
    'FORWARDED_FOR_IP',
    'HTTP_PROXY_CONNECTION'
);
foreach($proxy_headers as $x){
    if (isset($_SERVER[$x])){ die("You are using a proxy!") };
}
```

*Aggressive portscan detection (not recommended!!!):* *

```
$ports = array(8080,80,81,1080,6588,8000,3128,553,554,4480);
foreach($ports as $port) {
    if (@fsockopen($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $port, $errno, $errstr, 30)) {
        die("You are using a proxy!");
    }
}
```

*This method will slow down your server a lot. It will also generate a lot of false positives and it may trigger your visitors virusscanners / firewalls.

Further detection methods include [Detect and Block TOR exit nodes](https://check.torproject.org/cgi-bin/TorBulkExitList.py) and using many public proxy lists you can find with [Google](https://www.google.nl/?gws_rd=ssl#q=public+proxy+list). Just always keep in mind that using these methods will slow your server down exponentially! Which is why I recommend securing your server / website with different methods.

Answer (score 3):

Proxy detection is quite complicated because a host can become a proxy in a matter of seconds. Most proxy servers will hide the fact that they're a proxy so checking for HTTP headers is not enough. There are paid and free solutions via API (which is very simple to integrate and use). I've talked about them in another thread but I'll re-iterate some sources here as well.

Paid: 
[MaxMind](http://dev.maxmind.com/proxy-detection/) - Proxy detection via API, $5 / 1000 queries. One of the most well known for GeoIP database and their fraud check system, they also have a proxy detection API.

Free: 
[GetIPIntel](http://getipintel.net) - They allow up to 15 queries per minute for free. It's in active development and they claim to use machine learning to detect if an IP is a proxy or not. There are plugins for various CMSes that use this website and from my experience, the results are pretty accurate.

If you're having issues with only VPNs, check out W I T C H. It's not an API implementation, but it's still free.

Comment: You can download and import free LITE database with all known proxy and match it locally.

https://lite.ip2location.com/database/px4-ip-proxytype-country-region-city-isp

Answer (score 1):

You may check this ip2proxy library, https://github.com/ip2location/ip2proxy-php, if this will meet your needs.

Below are the sample codes:

```
require 'class.IP2Proxy.php';

$db = new \IP2Proxy\Database();
$db->open('./samples/IP2PROXY-IP-PROXYTYPE-COUNTRY-REGION-CITY-ISP.SAMPLE.BIN', \IP2Proxy\Database::FILE_IO);

$records = $db->getAll('1.0.241.135');

if ($records['isProxy'] == 1){
    //This is a proxy, you may return 404 or redirect to other custom error page
}
```